# How to make variable width a higher priority than a line break between divs in CSS?

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float

Here is the work I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/Jm6C4/1/

The page is structured like this:

```
<div id="hero">
    <div id="heroText">
        <!-- Text on the front of the homepage -->
    </div>
    <div id="heroImage">
        <!-- Image to match -->
    </div>
</div>

<div id="news">
    <div id="newsPane">
        <!-- Pane showing a recent article -->
    </div>
    <div id="emailPane">
        <!-- Form to subscribe to email newsletter -->
    </div>
</div>
```

The two top-level divs, hero and news, are two columns that are side by side when the webpage is full width. The two columns are floated left and right.

Right now what happens is when the page goes below the width of the two columns, the second column goes to the next line, below the first column, even though the first column can shrink below `max-width`. You can see this by going to the fiddle, and dragging the divider to the right to shrink the pane with the rendered result.

When the horizontal length of the webpage decreases below what both columns are, I want the second column to stay on the first line and the first column to start shrinking below `max-width` until it gets to `min-width` (which I haven't put in yet, but let's say 300px). When the first column gets to 300px, the second column should go to the next line, and the first column should be about 650px, since the second is 300px plus 50px margin in between.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to shift the order of the contents in html: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jm6C4/3/)

HTML:

```
<div id="news">
                    <div id="newsPane">
                        <div id="newsPaneText">
                            <h1>Title</h1>
                            <p>Praesent et tellus ac augue tempus scelerisque. Integer pellentesque dapibus ornare. Donec faucibus hendrerit nisl vel fermentum. Mauris nec arcu bibendum, pellentesque lorem tincidunt, tincidunt nibh. Praesent tempus pellentesque tempus.</p>
                            <p>Sed feugiat rutrum velit, eget faucibus dolor porta nec. Vivamus auctor eros tellus, at congue purus ultrices in.</p>
                            <p>Fusce at nisi est. Praesent ac blandit nulla, sed dictum enim. Nunc consectetur metus id tempor congue. Etiam sed enim quis nisl elementum egestas. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut cursus porttitor sagittis.</p>
                            <p>Maecenas vulputate odio id eleifend molestie. Ut quis sem eleifend, semper diam quis, accumsan erat. Maecenas faucibus tincidunt neque, vitae lacinia felis pellentesque in. Vestibulum commodo lorem eget purus sagittis, aliquet congue est cursus. In mattis, turpis scelerisque tincidunt posuere, lorem nisi vestibulum odio, ut scelerisque tortor mi et est. Suspendisse nisi nisl, interdum ac magna sit amet, consequat sodales augue. Maecenas dictum, erat ac elementum bibendum, sem sapien dapibus lectus, a dictum erat purus eget nisi. Pellentesque luctus tincidunt risus vitae gravida. Mauris justo augue, porta bibendum tincidunt quis, elementum feugiat mauris.</p>
                            <small>Article published on May 2, 2014</small>
                        </div>
                        <button id="newsReadMoreButton" class="largeButton" onclick="window.location.href = '/news/title';">Read more</button>
                    </div>
                    <div id="emailPane">
                        <div id="emailForm">
                            <label for="email">Enter your email address to get these important updates in your inbox.</label>
                            <input type="email" id="emailField" placeholder="you@example.com" />
                            <button id="emailSubmitButton" class="smallButton" onclick="submitEmailForm();">Continue</button>
                            <p id="emailFormStatus"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
<div id="hero">
                    <div id="heroText">
                        <p>This is not helpful text,</p>
                        <p>and the image has nothing to do with this website.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="heroImage">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I was able get the second column to stay on one line by wrapping both of the columns in a container by using a percentage for its width and then giving the columns widths with a sum of 100%.

See this: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jm6C4/2/)

Also, I think it may just be easier to use media queries instead of relying on `min-width`/`max-width`.

Comment: There's too big of a margin to the right of the second column... and using media-queries doesn't allow the columns to gradually scale. I was already going to use them to adjust the columns' positions when the screen is too narrow, but they're not an alternative to responsive web design.